# php.ini use multiple include paths - openbasedir restriction

Tags: php5, virtualhost, open-basedir

I need to allow an include path for a vhost subdomain on Plesk 10. I've edited the PHP PEAR path into /etc/php.ini as I'm happy for it to be globally available:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/pear/"
```

This works insofar as PHP is able to see the files in that directory when a script tries to include them, but I'm getting the dreaded openbasedir error:

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/pear/xxxx.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/subdomains/test/httpdocs/:/tmp/)
```

Am I right in saying that the subdomain or main domain can have a vhost.conf file in which I can alter the openbasedir allowed paths? I've tried searching out solutions but I'm afraid I can't quite see one yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah found it!

1) create vhost.conf for the subdomain: /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/subdomains/test/conf/vhost.conf

2) add the following:

```
   <Directory /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/subdomains/test/httpdocs>
      <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/subdomains/test/httpdocs:/tmp:/usr/share/pear"
      </IfModule>
      <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/subdomains/test/httpdocs:/tmp:/usr/share/pear"
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>
```

3) Configure plesk to recognise new vhost.conf

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain test.xxxx.com
```

4) Restart apache

```
service httpd restart
```