# Overriding vhost.conf to always allow PHP include access to directory

Tags: php, virtualhost

My predecessor in my job developed a simplistic newsletter system for our school's newspaper utilizing PEAR's Mail package. As I grow this system (and our site) we are constantly stuck with Plesk rewriting the vhost.conf file in which the PEAR include path has been manually entered.  This has become an unwieldy task to actually manage and keep running. There's been a "note" from both the previous developer and I to attempt to solve this problem, but we can't entirely figure it out.

I'm attempting a move to cPanel through another host, so hopefully it'll go away there, but until then, it can be tedious extremely difficult to get a solid uptake of the system without constant "web-presence."

I've searched around and haven't found a solution. I'm rather new to the server management scene (command line was non-existant till around a year ago. =/), so I haven't found anything. Any help would be useful.

"Similar Questions" popped [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/278180/php-ini-use-multiple-include-paths-openbasedir-restriction) up, but it still seems to rely on vhost.conf, and will still allow changes within Plesk to overwrite the changes.

Comment: If you are on VPS .. this means that you can edit the main config file `httpd.conf`, right?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP include path should be set in the php.ini file. It is possible to add settings in the httpd.conf file - I assume from what you're saying here that this is (a very insecure) shared hosting package? In which case you shouldn't have access to modify that.

You can change PHP settings via .htaccess files using the same syntax as in the httpd.conf files.

You can also override the settings within your PHP code using [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: No, I'm on a VPS. But the only method I've found is to modify the                                                                     vhost.conf and it works... until I make any minor change to the hosting environment via Plesk, the changes are reset.

Comment: Then change it in the php.ini - unless it's explicitly being overridden by plesk in the vhost file (as opposed to just being removed) the path will be fixed. I cannot see any benefit in using plesk nor cpanel for a vhost, but find it hard to believe plesk don't allow for use in a non-shared environment - and since its commercial software, have you contacted the developer?

Comment: Using Plesk to manage my VPS (its installed by default) allows me, as a non-sysadmin ability to easily manage my server. Any time I make a change (as in add a sub-domain) it gets overridden. I'm looking for something to avoid this, and I think that @LazyOne may have given me an actual answer. And I had seen problems with php.ini being explicitly denied access if it wasn't in vhost.conf.